Sharing Settings for Master-Detail Relationship
if the parent object has only read access, can the child have read and edit access in salesforce

In a master-detail relationship, the child’s access level is strictly governed by the parent object’s sharing model. If the parent is read-only, the child will also be read-only.

I believe this answer is factually incorrect. Sharing access for child records in master detail relationship is always controlled only by the parent sharing.

@PhilW updated the answer
